# Two http POST requests on submit

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, post

In my application, I have a form with some fields and a submit button. On click this button makes a POST request using express. I then use sequelize to add the form data to my database. Also, I am using mailer to send an email of the form data on every POST made. The problem is that each submit click makes two POST requests instead of just one.

This is my code for the POST request. Message is a sequelize model.

```
// Dependencies
// =============================================================

var Message = require("../models/message.js");

var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// Mailer options
//===============================================================
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
port: 587,
auth: {
    user: 'MYUSER',
    pass: 'MYPASS'
}
});



// Routes
// =============================================================

module.exports = function (app) {

app.post("/api/contact", function (req, res) {
    console.log("Message Data:");
    console.log(req.body);

    Message.create({
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        email: req.body.email,
        subject: req.body.subject,
        message: req.body.message,

    }).then(function (results) {
        var mailOptions = {
            from: 'FROM-EMAIL',
            to: 'TO-EMAIL',
            subject: results.subject,
            text: results.message
        };

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
            if (error) {
                return console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
            }
        });
    });
    res.end();
});

};
```

My front end:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>A-Scan</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron:900" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Materialize Icons -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Materialize CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css">
<!-- Materialize JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<!-- My CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
<!-- My JavaScript -->
<script src="assets/javascript/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <nav>

        <div class="nav-wrapper red darken-4 z-depth-3">
            <div class="customAlign left">
            </div>
            <a href="/" class="brand-logo white-text">A-Scan</a>
            <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="white-text button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>

            <p class="center brand-logo white-text headerFont" id="contactHeader" style="margin: 0px;">Contact</p>

            <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a href="/" class="white-text bold waves-effect waves-red"><i class="white-text material-icons left">home</i>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about" class="white-text bold waves-effect waves-red"><i class="white-text material-icons left">lightbulb_outline</i>Why
                        A-Scan?</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact" class="white-text bold waves-effect waves-red"><i class="white-text material-icons left">contact_mail</i>Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
        <li><a href="/"><i class="material-icons left sidenav-close">home</i>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about"><i class="material-icons left sidenav-close">lightbulb_outline</i>Why
                A-Scan?</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact"><i class="material-icons left sidenav-close">contact_mail</i>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
                <p style="font-size: 2em; font-weight: 300;">
                    <br>
                    Questions? Quotations?
                    <br><br>
                    Send us a message
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <form class="col s12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <input id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <input id="subject" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <textarea id="message" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                        <label for="textarea1">Message</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12">
                        <a id="submit" class="red darken-4 waves-effect waves-red btn">Submit</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12">
                        <h5 class=" grey-text text-darken-3">
                            Send us an email:
                        </h5>
                        <a href="mailto:shai@ascan-llc.com">shai@ascan-llc.com</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>

<script>

    $("#submit").on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var messageContent = {
            firstName: $("#first_name").val().trim(),
            lastName: $("#last_name").val().trim(),
            email: $("#email").val().trim(),
            subject: $("#subject").val().trim(),
            message: $("#message").val().trim(),
        }

        $.post("/api/contact", messageContent, function (data) {

        }).then(function (data) {
            $("#first_name").val('');
            $("#last_name").val('');
            $("#email").val('');
            $("#subject").val('');
            $("#message").val('');
        });

    })

</script>
```

Comment: POST request is initiated client side. If your application is receiving two POST requests then the issue is in the front end, not the back end. You'll need to post your front end form handler code.

Comment: The code seems right. Are you sure these are 2 POST requests, and not OPTIONS + POST?